# Why the login_requried decorator doesn't work after I log out from the account?

Tags: python, django

Working on a project using Django 3.2, I have been added new features to the project by adding a login/register page for the user. To do that, I used which I used this library provided by Django from django.contrib.auth.models import User, and as well in the views I used from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout library.

After I finished the login/register successfully I decided to do the authenticate the home page for the reason that the user without an account can't have access to the home page. To do that I used the decorators from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required, and I used it on every view that I want to authenticate for the unregistered user. To understand it better will show the code below:
views.py

```
from django.http.response import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.utils import timezone
from django.db.models import Count
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.contrib import messages

from .models import *
from .models import __str__
from .forms import CreateUserForm

# Create your views here.

@login_required(login_url='login/')
def home(request):
    count_item = todo.objects.count()
    
    all_items = todo.objects.all().order_by("created")

    context = {'all_items': all_items, 'count_item':count_item}

    return render(request, 'html/home.html', context)

@login_required(login_url='login/')
def add_todo(request):
    current_date = timezone.now()
    new_item= todo(content = request.POST["content"])
    new_item.save()
    return redirect('/')

@login_required(login_url='login/')
def delete_todo(request, todo_id):
    item_to_delete = todo.objects.get(id=todo_id)
    item_to_delete.delete()
    return redirect('/')


def login_user(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        # print('USER:', user)

        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('/') 
    return render(request, 'html/login.html')


def logoutUser(request):
    logout(request)
    return redirect('login/')

def register_user(request):
    form = CreateUserForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CreateUserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.save()

            user = authenticate(request, username=user.username, password=request.POST.get('password1'))

            print("USER:",user)

            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('/')

    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'html/register.html', context)
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from django.views.generic.base import RedirectView

from . import views


app_name = 'todo'




urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name="home"),
    path('add_todo/', views.add_todo),
    path('delete_todo/<int:todo_id>/', views.delete_todo),
    path('login/', views.login_user, name='login'),
    path('logout/', views.logoutUser, name='logout'),
    path('register/', views.register_user, name="register"),
]
```

forms.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm, fields
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django import forms




class CreateUserForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']
```

The problem that I'm having is that when first open the page in the localhost the authentication is working, I cannot have access to the home page without registering or login to the page, but after I log in with a registered user and log out, the authentication doesn't work, I can have access to the homepage after I log out.

I'm not sure why it's not working after I log in.

Would appreciate any response Thanks!

Comment: Try to add: LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#login-redirect-url

Answer (score 0):

You could define e dedicated parameter in settings.py, for your project it would be :
`LOGIN_URL = '/todo/login/'`

Then, in your views.py, just use `@login_required`
If your path change for any reason, you will only have to change it only once.

You can also try to modify your logout view to ensure there is no residual side effect from your database (the key command is [`flush()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/3.2/topics/http/sessions/#django.contrib.sessions.backends.base.SessionBase.flush)):

```py
def logoutUser(request):
    logout(request)
    request.session.flush()
    return redirect(reverse("todo:home"))
```

Comment: Did that, still doesn't work

Comment: what happens? could you add the code for login and logout views?

Comment: Its still the same, after I log out, I can have access to the home page. The code for the login, logout as well is at views.py, It at the question.

Comment: You could try to use `request.session.flush()` in your logout view (I edited my post accordingly)

Answer (score 0):

```
def logoutUser(request):
    logout(request)
    render(request, 'html/login.html')
```

try send request to client.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).